# Traversing a directory and returning text in python

Tags: python

Does anyone have code to traverse a directory and sub directory while searching for a text value? Then once found return the values in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "searching for a text value"? Are you looking for a specific file?

Comment: Or do you mean like `grep` through the directories? It would be helpful if you could tell us the purpose of this command. As much as I like Python (and I do), sometimes there are better tools. Also, what platform are you using?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  Here's a start: [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, `os.walk()` returns a Python generator that traverses a given directory tree. For each directory encountered in the tree, the generator returns a 3-tuple of `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. You will need to use `os.walk()` inside a loop

Then, the built-in `open()` function is used to return a `file` object from which you can read the content of the file. `read()` will read the full content of the file, while `readlines()` will read one line at a time.

Assuming that the text you are looking for cannot be on multiple lines so that it is safe to process your files one line at a time, you could do something along these lines:

```
import os
import re

matching_files = []

root = "/path/to/root/folder/you/want/to/walk"
# Navigate the directory structure starting at root
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    # For each file in the current directory
    for file_name in files:
        # Reconstruct the full path
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        # Open the file
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            # Read the file one line at a time
            for line in f.readlines():
                 # Look for your text in the current line
                 if re.findall(r'text_you_are_searching_for', line):
                     matching_files.append(file_path)
```

You can get more details in the online docs about

- [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)
- Python [file objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)
- [Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) in Python

Comment: I have tired a couple of examples on the site but I am completely new to python...
text_storage = open(path,'r').read()


quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',text_storage)
for quote in quotes:
     print text_storage

Comment: @user1469433 so you are trying to find text inside the files, not inside the file names, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation for `os.walk()`, give it a try, and come back if you can't make it work.

Comment: Hi, I am on a windows system. Basically I need to move through a clear case repository and found all text that matches a criteria such as text that is hard coded so things like Something="Something Else" would be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your own grep you can use `os.walk()` and some basic file I/O. We need more information on what specifically is required before we can produce code.

Comment: Basically we have a collection of java files that may contain some hard coded text. Most of the text we use is stored in properties files so would look like (labels.getString("SomeText"). However, there are hard coded values through files that may not be referencing the relevant properties files via labels and this is what we need to filer out...

Comment: @user1469433 It could help if you edited your original question to clearly state what you are trying to achieve instead of adding details inside comments to answers.